# How to convert a numpy array view to opencv matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, stride

I'm using opencv v2.2 to do some template matching on ndarrays, and I had great trouble with memory leaks when using their wrapped method `cv.fromarray()`.  Rather than plug the memory leaks I avoided the `fromarray()` function and used `cv.SetData` directly, like this:

```
assert foo_numpy.dtype == 'uint8'
assert foo_numpy.ndim == 3
h, w = foo_numpy.shape[:2]
foo_cv = cv.CreateMat(h, w, cv.CV_8UC3)
cv.SetData(foo_cv, foo_numpy.data, foo_numpy.strides[0])
```

This seems to solve the memory leaks and `foo_cv` seems to be deallocated properly when it goes out of scope.  However, now I have the issue where if `foo_numpy` is just a slice/view on a bigger array, I'm not permitted `foo_numpy.data` (cannot get single-segment buffer for discontiguous array).  At the moment I'm working around this by making `foo_numpy.copy()` if `foo_numpy.base != None`, which permits getting the buffer on the new copy.   But I have the feeling this is unnecessary, the slice has the `__array_struct__` and `__array_interface__` so I should be able to just stride it with the appropriate stepsizes somehow?  I'm not sure how to do it in a nice way, because the base of this one can also be a view on another larger array ad infinitum.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with what you were trying to do is that the array data you're interested in (ie. `foo_np_view`) is actually only stored in one place i.e. `foo_np.data`, and the OpenCV `SetData` method doesn't provide any way to specify stride settings that would allow you to skip the bytes that are not part of `foo_np_view`.

You can, however, get around this problem using Numpy’s `tostring()` method, which turns an array (or views therein) into a byte string:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cv
>>> foo_np = np.array( 255 * np.random.rand( 200 , 300 , 3 ), dtype = 'uint8' )
>>> foo_np_view = foo_np [ 50:150:2 , 10:290:5 , : ]
>>> h,w,d = foo_np_view.shape
>>> foo_cv = cv.CreateMat( h , w , cv.CV_8UC3 )
```

Recreating the original problem:

```
>>> cv.SetData( foo_cv , foo_np_view.data, foo_np_view.strides[0] )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: cannot get single-segment buffer for discontiguous array
```

Using the `tostring()` method (see below for explanation of the stride setting):

```
>>> cv.SetData( foo_cv , foo_np_view.tostring() , w * d * foo_np_view.dtype.itemsize )
>>> np.array_equal( np.asarray( foo_cv ) , foo_np_view )
True
```

The value `w * d * foo_np_view.dtype.itemsize` gives us a stride value identical to that of `foo_np_view.copy()`, which is necessary as the string representations of the view and its copy are identical:

```
>>> foo_np_view.copy().tostring() == foo_np_view.tostring()
True
>>> foo_np_view.copy().strides[0] == w * d * foo_np_view.dtype.itemsize
True
```

Comment: thanks, that appears to work , but i don't think i can gain any performance over my current solution (making a copy of the array), because the tostring() method seems to return a copy anyway.  correct me if i'm wrong..